# Printing Receipt on Star Micronics TSP 650 Printer through iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, printing

I am using Star iOS SDK to print receipts (like a restaurant bill) but am facing problems implementing column settings and cell spacing for proper alignment. I have checked out the documentation but have not found something useful.

The line code manual has some signals/commands which I am unable to understand. Can anyone help me out with that?

Answer (score 1):

The commands referenced in the Line Mode manual need to be converted into bytes and then sent to the printer. The StarIO iOS SDK package you downloaded has a manual called "README_StarIO_POSPrinter_iOS_SDK.pdf". (http://www.starmicronics.com/absolutefm/absolutefm/afmviewfaq.aspx?faqid=175) Did you check out pages 9-15? The StarIO framework is explained here.

Specific to your question about sending commands, page 13 shows you how to write to the port using a byte array, but make sure you add StarIO.framework and open the communication port first.

From the manual:

```
//Set a byte array to send to the printer
//command = { A, B, C, D, Feed 3mm, Full Cut}
unsigned char command = {0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x1B, 0x7A, 0x00, 0x1B, 0x64, 0x02};

Uint bytesWritten = 0;

@Try
{ 
   While(bytesWritten < (sizeof command)) 
   {
    bytesWritten += [port writePort: command : bytesWritten : sizeof command - bytesWritten];
   }
}
@Catch(PortException)
{
   //There was an error writing to the port
}
```

Also described is how to close ports (make sure you close every opened port) and getting printer status.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked. Anyhow do you know how to add full Cut after printing? Like which command I need to append at end of my receipt data that make printer to cut the page.

Answer (score 1):

I talked to SDK developers of start micronics, as I was facing the same problem using TSP100 model. Here is the reply from one of their tech guy.

> "Unlike most of our other models the TSP100 series is a bit unique in that it is raster only meaning that it does not have the text formatting commands that our other printers do (ie, the printer just prints whatever receipt image you send it).  Any formatting would be done in your application however you would like to do it before creating the image to send to the printer"

So this is clear that you have to maintain the column width, formatting, alignment etc everything by yourself.

Comment: If anyone wants it, I created a driver that I think is much better than the Star driver. https://github.com/gabebear/TSPPrintingExample

Comment: @Gabe by any chance, do you have a ionic/cordova plugin for printing in TSP100 via bluetooth? The existing plugins out there do not work.

Comment: @EsthonWood I don't have any Blueooth versions of the printer, but the commands are likely the same... From the looks of it the TSP shows up as a Bluetooth2.1 MFi device, so you'd need to to some analysis of an existing app to figure out how to interact with it similar to what I did to get Atari's MFi controller working. https://github.com/gabebear/AtariDuoHack